# Ruby spawn process, capturing STDOUT/STDERR, while behaving as if it were spawned regularly

Tags: ruby, io, subprocess, pty

What I'm trying to achieve:

- From a Ruby process, spawning a subprocess
- The subprocess should print as normal back to the terminal. By "normal", I mean the process shouldn't miss out color output, or ignore user input (STDIN).
- For that subprocess, capturing STDOUT/STDERR (jointly) e.g. into a String variable that can be accessed after the subprocess is dead. Escape characters and all.

Capturing STDOUT/STDERR is possible by passing a different IO pipe, however the subprocess can then detect that it's not in a `tty`. For example `git log` will not print characters that influence text color, nor use it's pager.

Using a `pty` to launch the process essentially "tricks" the subprocess into thinking it's being launched by a user. As far as I can tell, this is exactly what I want, and the result of this essentially ticks all the boxes.

My general tests to test if a solution fits my needs is:

- Does it run `ls -al` normally?
- Does it run `vim` normally?
- Does it run `irb` normally?

The following Ruby code is able to check all the above:

```rb
to_execute = "vim"

output = ""
require 'pty'
require 'io/console'

master, slave = PTY.open
slave.raw!

pid = ::Process.spawn(to_execute, :in => STDIN, [:out, :err] => slave)
slave.close
master.winsize = $stdout.winsize
Signal.trap(:WINCH) { master.winsize = $stdout.winsize }
Signal.trap(:SIGINT) { ::Process.kill("INT", pid) }

master.each_char do |char|
  STDOUT.print char
  output.concat(char)
end

::Process.wait(pid)
master.close
```

This works for the most part but it turns out it's not perfect. For some reason, certain applications seem to fail to switch into a `raw` state. Even though `vim` works perfectly fine, it turned out neovim did not. At first I thought it was a bug in neovim but I have since been able to reproduce the problem using the Termion crate for the Rust language.

By setting to raw manually (`IO.console.raw!`) before executing, applications like neovim behave as expected, but then applications like `irb` do not.

Oddly spawning *another* pty in Python, *within this pty*, allows the application to work as expected (using `python -c 'import pty; pty.spawn("/usr/local/bin/nvim")'`). This obviously isn't a real solution, but interesting nonetheless.

For my actual question I guess I'm looking towards any help to resolving the weird `raw` issue or, say if I've completely misunderstood tty/pty, any different direction to where/how I should look at the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[edited: see the bottom for the amended update]

Figured it out :)

To really understand the problem I read up a lot on how a PTY works. I don't think I really understood it properly until I drew it out. Basically PTY could be used for a Terminal emulator, and that was the simplest way to think of the data flow for it:

```
keyboard -> OS -> terminal -> master pty -> termios -> slave pty -> shell
                                               |
                                               v
 monitor <- OS <- terminal <- master pty <- termios
```

(note: this might not be *100%* correct, I'm definitely no expert on the subject, just posting it incase it helps anybody else understand it)

So the important bit in the diagram that I hadn't really realised was that when you type, the only reason you see your input on screen is because it's passed *back* (left-wards) to the master.

So first thing's first - this ruby script should first set the tty to raw (`IO.console.raw!`), it can restore it after execution is finished (`IO.console.cooked!`). This'll make sure the keyboard inputs aren't printed by this parent Ruby script.

Second thing is the slave itself should not be raw, so the `slave.raw!` call is removed. To explain this, I originally added this because it removes extra return carriages from the output: running `echo hello` results in `"hello\r\n"`. What I missed was that this return carriage is a key instruction to the terminal emulator (whoops).

Third thing, the process should only be talking to the slave. Passing `STDIN` felt convenient, but it upsets the flow shown in the diagram.

This brings up a new problem on how to pass user input through, so I tried this. So we basically pass `STDIN` to the `master`:

```
  input_thread = Thread.new do
    STDIN.each_char do |char|
      master.putc(char) rescue nil
    end
  end
```

that *kind of* worked, but it has its own issues in terms of some interactive processes weren't receiving a key some of the time. Time will tell, but using `IO.copy_stream` instead appears to solve that issue (and reads much nicer of course).

```
input_thread = Thread.new { IO.copy_stream(STDIN, master) }
```

---

update 21st Aug:

So the above example mostly worked, but for some reason keys like CTRL+c still wouldn't behave correctly. I even looked up [other people's approach](https://github.com/alltom/coolterm/commit/73ff4a95359139aeb18c82be6fba844d459793be) to see what I could be doing wrong, and effectively it seemed the same approach - as `IO.copy_stream(STDIN, master)` was successfully sending `3` to the master. None of the following seemed to help at all:

```
master.putc 3
master.putc "\x03"
master.putc "\003"
```

Before I went and delved into trying to achieve this in a lower level language I tried out 1 more thing - the block syntax. Apparently the block syntax magically fixes this problem.

To prevent this answer getting a bit too verbose, the following appears to work:

```rb
require 'pty'
require 'io/console'

def run
  output = ""

  IO.console.raw!

  input_thread = nil

  PTY.spawn('bash') do |read, write, pid|
    Signal.trap(:WINCH) { write.winsize = STDOUT.winsize }
    input_thread = Thread.new { IO.copy_stream(STDIN, write) }

    read.each_char do |char|
      STDOUT.print char
      output.concat(char)
    end

    Process.wait(pid)
  end

  input_thread.kill if input_thread

  IO.console.cooked!
end

Bundler.send(:with_env, Bundler.clean_env) do
  run
end
```

Comment: This works great for sending input as a user, but how would you send input to that process programmatically - let's say coming from a result of another function later on.

Comment: you just need to print or puts into the `write` variable, so either keep a reference of that for your other function, or have another stream to copy it from like it's copying from STDIN on this line `input_thread = Thread.new { IO.copy_stream(STDIN, write) }`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Using your sample code, trying to use input_thread.puts does nothing when used after "read.each_cha.." and write.puts behaves the same. Any idea why i cannot send input form outside of the "PTY.spawn" block?

Comment: I think I need to see more of your code to understand your problem, maybe it's worth a new question? You can link to it here if you do. Either way, `write.puts` should work anywhere as long as the block hasn't ended (as after it's ended, it'll be closed), so as long as you're protecting it with `Process.wait(pid)` like above, it'll work until the process is over.